# Phone is plugged into computer via USB, charging but not entering adb mode

Tags: adb, linux

I am on Linux, so this is not a driver problem. I have a Huawei Union, USB Debugging is enabled in developer options, and I have previously been able to use ADB when the device is plugged in via USB. The phone displays, "USB debugging is on" in the notification tray, and ADB just works. Now, when I plug in the phone, the phone does not show this notification and `adb devices` shows nothing. Is this a problem with my USB cord or one of the ports on the devices? Because it worked just fine when I got all three parts (the laptop, the phone, and the cord) two weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the usb cable that came with your device? Check another usb port on the laptop, reboot the laptop if another port doesnt work either. If that does not help, check another usb cable. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

USB debugging on Linux works far better if the adbd deamon is running as root. Try these commands:

```
adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
```